# EmberJS error while processing route

Tags: ember.js

I am grabbing json data from a service that I cannot change. I am trying to load this data into an Ember.ArrayController.

Error I am dealing with:

*Error while processing route: profiles Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object*

data format looks like this

```
var testData =
{
    "CustomerProfilesResult": [
        { "DOB": "10\/23\/1969 12:00:00 AM", "DateEnrolled": "7\/10\/2014 12:00:00 AM", "FirstName": "Rob", "LastName": "Weiner", "ProfileId": 1 }, 
        { "DOB": "10\/23\/1979 12:00:00 AM", "DateEnrolled": "10\/3\/2014 12:00:00 AM", "FirstName": "Repub", "LastName": "Smitty", "ProfileId": 1 }, 
        { "DOB": "10\/23\/1978 12:00:00 AM", "DateEnrolled": "10\/17\/2014 12:00:00 AM", "FirstName": "Democrat", "LastName": "Johnson", "ProfileId": 1 }, 
        { "DOB": "10\/23\/1996 12:00:00 AM", "DateEnrolled": "10\/18\/2014 12:00:00 AM", "FirstName": "Itchy", "LastName": "Digger", "ProfileId": 1 }]
};
```

This should be simple... but Ember only wants it when its not wrapped in the CustomerProfilesResult. I've tried returning

```
        return Ember.$.getJSON(getProfiles)
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        }).error(function(){
            alert('error happened... should have caught this.')
        });
```

and

> ```
>   return Ember.$.getJSON(getProfiles)
>         .success(function(data){
>             return data.CustomerProfilesResult;
>         }).error(function(){
>             alert('error happened... should have caught this.')
>         });
> ```

both of which fail with

but during testing I have returned

```
return testData.CustomerProfilesResult;
```

just fine so its confusing. I know its something stupid I'm missing... help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`success` doesn't care about the value you return to it, so it isn't returned to the model hook when the promise is resolved.  The original json data is sent to both the success call and the `then` portion of the promise.

```
return Ember.$.getJSON(getProfiles)
.then(function(data){
   return data.CustomerProfilesResult;
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hafaj/edit

Comment: thanks, I knew it had to be something I didn't yet grasp. Suffering through the learning process... trying to keep my classic past out of my mind. Man what a struggle.